# Python - web scrape data from xml

Tags: python, web-scraping, xml-parsing

have a little issue webscraping xml from web. It's a meteo data page for which I want to manually enter the city name in my python code and get data for it from xml file (temperature, humidity, pressure).

It's the first time I'm dealing with xml and not sure how to approach - anybody that could help me please?

When I run the code below I get printed everything (much longer data sheet than the one I copied here).

What I want to get is:

City name: City name
Temperature: 13.0
Pressure: 1013.9
Humidity: 86

> url ="linkx2xml.xml"
> page = requests.get(url)
> root = etree.parse(page.content).getroot()
> instruments = root.find('CityIme')
> instrument = instruments.find_all("City 1 Name")
> for grandchild in instrument:
> temperature, pressure, humid = grandchild.find('Temp'), grandchild.find('Press'), grandchild.find('humid')
> print(temperature.text, pressure.text, humid.text)

Link to xml: https://vrijeme.hr/hrvatska_n.xml

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a python library called ElementTree I suppose. You could also use other compatible implementations of the same API, such as lxml, and cElementTree in the Python standard library itself.

First build an Element instance root from the XML, e.g. with the XML function, or by parsing a file and then iterate over the children and search for whatever child tags you would like to retrieve:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

#get xml file and parse
url ="linkx2xml.xml" 
page = requests.get(url)
tree = etree.parse(page.content)
root = tree.getroot()
#iterate over every child of the root with the type 'Grad'
for child in root.iter('Grad'):
    # save cityname
    cityname = child.find('GradIme')
    # get child_element which contains the weather dataa
    data = child.find("Podatci")
    # save weather data located under Podcatci element
    temperature = data.find('Temp') 
    pressure = data.find('Tlak')
    humid = data.find('Vlaga') 
    print(cityname.text +":\t"+temperature.text + "\t" + pressure.text +"\t"+ humid.text)
```

Here the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: Yes, I had an issue posting this here so finally removed whole code and left part without import part :-)
If I replace this: for type_tag in root.findall('Grad'): 
into
for type_tag in root.findall('Bjelovar'):
does it mean that code below is only getting temp for it?
Unfortunatelly, I did go through the documentation, but I'm begginer level so expect another stupid question.
Also, will test in about an hour.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @geni0us, as far as I know you can only search for tags (like 'GradIme' or 'Podatci') and not for attributes. 'Bjelovar' is a attribute of a tag 'GadIme'. Please just test my sample code I added after your comment, maybe this will help you. The comments I provided shall also be helpful. If there are questions left just comment here

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it seems that this line prints complete xml: tree = etree.parse(page.content) and after it it does nothing. Will need to debug..

Comment: I was working with a local copy of your xml and this worked perfectly:

tree = etree.parse("C:/workspace/hrvatska_n.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for grandchild in root.iter('Grad'):
    cityname = grandchild.find('GradIme')
    data = grandchild.find("Podatci")
    temperature = data.find('Temp') 
    pressure = data.find('Tlak')
    humid = data.find('Vlaga') 
    print(cityname.text +":\t"+temperature.text + "\t" + pressure.text +"\t"+ humid.text)

Comment: Yes, that is true - it does work when I download the file locally, but it doesn't work when getting data from web which is sort of a must :-/ let me see how to do that..

Comment: aaaand solved with parser = etree.XMLParser()
:-)

Comment: Any chance that you could point me how to extract data for only one city? :-/

Answer (score 1):

Thank you bloodscript, for putting me on right track!
From this, I was able to provide solution with this code below. I'm pretty sure this could be solved with much better code, but in the eyes of the beginner it does what it needs to be done :-)
Only this line is something to think about:

```
if root[i][0].text == grad:
```

I believe it should be somehow, better.

```
def tempxml(grad):

    parser = etree.XMLParser()

    with urlopen('https://vrijeme.hr/hrvatska_n.xml') as f:
        tree = etree.parse(f, parser)
        root = tree.getroot()

    i = 0
    for child in root:
        #print(child.tag, child.attrib)
        if root[i][0].text == grad:
            city = root[i][0].text
            data = child.find("Podatci")
            temperature = data.find('Temp') 
            pressure = data.find('Tlak')
            humid = data.find('Vlaga') 
            return city, temperature.text, pressure.text, humid.text
        i+=1
```